# Is there any way to enable Administrator account from an limited user account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Unfortunately, I removed my user account from administrators group and my default administrator account was disabled by default. So now i am unable to perform any administrative task. 
Is there any way to add my user account in administrator group OR Enable default administrator account in windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on a corporate network then you can ask your domain administrator to log in and fix things.

If not then boot the computer from some other medium and use tools to reset the administrator password. Personally I use [this bootable CD image](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/), but there are many variations of these.

Comment: Additionally, a good tool to have is the Ultimate Boot CD for Windows http://ubcd4win.com/

Comment: Aye, there any many variations possible and some have significantly more functionality than others. The I linked to can only do the task the OP asked, which is why I selected that one.

Comment: @Hennes: - Thanks a lot sir, Done with help of Hiren Boot.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to add my user account in administrator group OR Enable default administrator account in windows 7?

Here is something for you to think about:

How secure would the security be if a regular user could self-promote himself to system god?

The whole security system is EXACTLY DESIGNED NOT TO ALLOW THAT. Common sense.

You could have made a password recovery disc when installing.

When not, reinstall time?

Comment: - Thanks for your reply Sir, I am sorry, At trouble time, i forgot this common sense. Thanks a lot for your response. Everything are fine now.

Comment: Windows is indeed designed to not allow an unprivileged user to elevate to Administrator - *unless* said user happens to have unrestricted physical access to the machine, in which case attempting to prevent it would be futile.  Also, if you'd read the question carefully you'd have realized that a password recovery disk would have been no use whatsoever, since the OP did not forget his password.